# Wrong icacls command not giving any error on being called by CreateProcessW function

Tags: c++, window, createprocess

I am trying to call the CreateProcessW() function to call dos command icacls in my C++ code . However this CreateProcessW() is not responding correctly to icacls command . I can say this because for negative testing i passed wrong icacls command to CreateProcessW() function an it just didnt throw any error.

However same command was failing in command prompt

I am attaching the code here

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <atomic>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::wstring command_line(L"icacls XXXCCCCC");//throws error with command prompt 

    STARTUPINFOW startup_info;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info;

    size_t len(command_line.size());
    std::vector<wchar_t> buff(len + 1);
    std::copy(command_line.begin(), command_line.end(), buff.begin());
    buff[len] = 0;

    GetStartupInfoW(&startup_info);
    BOOL result(CreateProcessW(nullptr, &buff[0], 0, 0, false, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, 0, 0,
        &startup_info, &process_info));

    if (!result)
    {
        std::cout << "FAIL" << std::endl;
        std::wcout << "  command line: <" << command_line << ">" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "PASS" << std::endl;
        std::wcout << "  command line: <" << command_line << ">" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: CreateProcess succeeded. It ran the command you asked for. Now, if you wanted to get the result code from that command or parse the output to detect and error that's a different thing, but as far as CreateProcess is concerned it did exactly what you asked for.

Comment: Thats what my question is , that why it ran . Its a negative scenario . This is the wrong command there is no such parameters or files named XXXCCCCC......

Comment: when you will run the same command from command prompt it will fail , and hence this code also when run should go to if condition and print FAIL

Comment: Your expectation of what CreateProcess does and what would constitute a failure is incorrect. Success for CreateProcess means it successfully loaded and began executing whatever you asked it to load. That executable could crash, print out an error, return a particular value that for it indicates an error, but none of that matters to CreateProcess because it did what you asked and created a process. If you need to decide if executing a program was a success or failure you cannot expect CreateProcess to tell you because it does not know.

Comment: Failure to CreateProcess means it could not find, load, or run the executable you asked for. When you receive an error at the command prompt it isn't because the program didn't run, it is because it did run and the result was to print an informative message telling you that you gave it invalid input.